# How can I get value in xml using python?

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml file like this:

```
<component apiversion="" class="BSP" condition="" group="Board" subgroup="s7g2_sk" variant="" vendor="balabala" version="1.1.1.1">
      <description>SK Board Support Files</description>
      <originalPack>board_s7g2_sk.1.3.0.pack</originalPack>
    </component>
```

I want to extract subgroup value: s7g2_sk, how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Python has a number of XML manipulation libraries, both bundled and 3rd-party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [lxml](http://lxml.de) library allows to do this easily :

```
from lxml import etree

xml="""    
<component apiversion="" class="BSP" condition="" group="Board" subgroup="s7g2_sk" variant="" vendor="balabala" version="1.1.1.1">
      <description>SK Board Support Files</description>
      <originalPack>board_s7g2_sk.1.3.0.pack</originalPack>
    </component>    
"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
print(root.get('subgroup'))
#>>> s7g2_sk
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, assuming an accessible file called test.xml:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.attrib['subgroup']) # s7g2_sk
```